# Multiple conditions within if_else, if else and if statements

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, multiple-conditions

Consider the following data:

```
Names <- c("name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name1")
Methods <- c("method1","method2", "method2", "method1", "method2")
Amount <- c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25)
df <- data.frame(Names, Methods, Amount)
```

I want to create a new variable for the dataframe based on a condition within a condition of the df as a new column.
I tried it based on 1 conditions and that worked:

```
df <- mutate(df, new_column = if_else(Methods=="method2", 0.05 + Amount * 1.5, NULL))
```

However how can I get a condition within this condition, to get for example:

name1 with method 2 and then give the new_column a value of 0.25 + amount * 0.5 ?

I tried the following code:

```
df <- mutate(df, new_column = if_else(Names=="name1",
if_else(Methods=="method2", 0.25 + Amount * 0.5, NULL)))
```

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
mutate(df, new_column = ifelse(Methods=="method2" & Names=="name1", 0.05 + Amount * 1.5, 
                                ifelse(Names=="name2", 0.05 + Amount * 1.5, NA
                                )))

  Names Methods Amount new_column
1 name1 method1      5       7.55
2 name2 method2     10      15.05
3 name3 method2     15      22.55
4 name4 method1     20         NA
5 name1 method2     25      37.55
```

The difference between ifelse and if_else is that (from `?if_else`)

> compared to the base ifelse(), this function is more strict. It checks
> that true and false are the same type. This strictness makes the
> output type more predictable, and makes it somewhat faster.

It also makes it less flexible.

If you have many of these conditions, you should use `case_when()` as @SamR mentioned.

```
mutate(df, new_column = case_when(
                                  Methods=="method2"& Names=="name1"~ 0.05 + Amount * 1.5, 
                                  Names=="name2"~ 0.05 + Amount * 1.5, 
                                  TRUE ~ NA_real_
                               ))
  Names Methods Amount new_column
1 name1 method1      5       7.55
2 name2 method2     10      15.05
3 name3 method2     15      22.55
4 name4 method1     20         NA
5 name1 method2     25      37.55
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer! It is clear to me.
However, I still do not know how I can use it with a 'double' condition. So that for example: name1 in combination with method 2 gives output: 0.5 + amount * 1.5. And name1 in combination with method 1 gives output: 1.0 + amount * 0.5.
Is this possible?

Comment: you can use `Methods=="method2"& Names=="name1"`, I edited the answer.